# How many rows can the following SQL query return?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, count

sql. There is a table T with an id field (optionally unique) that contains N rows. How many rows can the following SQL query return?

```
select * from T
inner join (
    select count(*) as cnt from T 
    union all select count(*) as cnt from T
) as TA on TA.cnt = T.id
inner join (
    select count(*) as cnt from T 
    union select count(*) as cnt from T
) as TB on TB.cnt = T.id;
```

I have some options:

- only N rows
- from 0 to N rows
- from 2N to 4N rows

or can you name some other options ?

Comment: Nobody can tell for sure without knowing the schéma of the table T. How the id are generated...

Comment: Consider this: `select * from T inner join (one_row) inner join (two_rows)`. Now, if T.id is *assumed* to be unique.. that should get to some bounds. Making it "optionally" unique changes answers: pick if it is unique or not.

Comment: what is "TA.cnt = T.id" OR "TB.cnt = T.id"? is that correct?

Comment: @db1975 Yes it is

Comment: Further, from above, consider that if the first join succeeds (1x multiplicity) the latter will as well (2x multiplicity). Then the two cases (assuming a unique ID) are "count matches an arbitrary value" and "count doesn't match an arbitrary value", which should be easy to work out. If `id` is constraint to `[0, count)`, then that's yet another detail which should be considered.

Comment: it can only 0 to 2 because you get max two rows for ta as for TB and each can mach the id in T

Answer (score 4):

This query returns either no rows or 2 rows (with all three columns having the same value).

Rationale:

- The `union all` subquery (aliased `TA`) returns 2 rows, each containing the same value, that is the count of records in `T`.
- The `union` subquery deduplicates its result and returns a single record, also containing the row count of the table
- What happens next depends whether there is a record in the table whose `id` is equal to that number.

  - If such record exists, then the query returns 2 rows: one for each row generated by the `union all` subquery.
  - If there is no such record, the query return no rows at all.

So assuming this dataset:

```
id
--
1
2
```

There are two rows in the table, and `id` `2` exists, so the query gives you two rows with that id.

If we change this to:

```
id
--
1
2
3
5
```

There are four rows but not `id` `4`. The query comes up empty.

Comment: Small error there. You said “each of the `union all` queries”, but there’s only *one* `union all`. The other is a plain `union`, and since the two sides of it are the same, it will always return exactly 1 row.

Comment: I still get 4 rows. T one row with value 2, times 2 for subquery 1, times 2 for subquery 2.

Comment: Now I see the union [distinct]... Yes, it's 2 rows.

Comment: @jarlh: yes, your comments were right. Bohemian's point fixes the answer and makes it consistent with your testing.

Answer (score 0):

0 rows if T.Id does not contain the value 2.
2 rows id T.Id contains the value 2